vs code auto completion
I followed a YouTube tutorial, but I can't seem to get the autocomplete working as shown.
For example, in the tutorial, when typing app.listen, it automatically shows the expected parameters in gray (with autocompletion). It looks something like this:

However, in my VS Code, it doesn't behave the same way. When I type app.listen, the autocompletion doesn’t appear, and I have to manually type the rest, like () => {}. It's quite frustrating and slows me down:

Does anyone know which VS Code extensions I should install? I think I might need one or more.
Updates on 22nd Oct
The following solutions are available, will collect more later.

Codeium (free): Fast and accurate, highly recommended.
Amazon Q (free): In my experience, this product is suck and does not perform well.
GitHub Copilot (paid): no chance to try, since I have above two, I don't think I will pay for this tool
cursor: will update later

Will keep update if there are more free solutions for choice

It's likely they used an AI tool like GitHub Copilot (paid) and Codeium (free), which none are preinstalled. I use Codeium and it works really well with no cost: https://codeium.com
